# Replace text and special character in linux

Tags: linux, bash

How to replace

```
<u>Some texts need to be underlined</u>

                by

\underline{Some texts need to be underlined}
```

in linux by "sed" or any other means?

Comment: that is probably a general linux question and not a latex question

Comment: @campa it will probably also be greedy, sadly I don't think `sed` supports the non-greedy `?` marker, so this will not work if there are several of these on the same line

Comment: @daleif True. In fact `sed 's/<u>/\\underline{/g;s/<\/u>/}/g'` might solve both problems. But again, off-topic indeed.

Comment: Thanks it worked, sorry for posting in the wrong forum.